# Ionic - Show Splash Screen When Switch Apps on Android

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm trying to hide my application screen when user is in switching app mode. I tried to show splashscreen when application is paused but it is not working. The application is still taking screenshot automatically when user switching the app. Anyway, I did try to install `cordova-plugin-privacyscreen` and it is working but this plugin is also disabling user from taking screenshot manually. Is there any workaround to enable manual screenshot when using this plugin?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to show splash screen but you can blur the screen when going to background using this plugin: [cordova-plugin-blurry-privacy-screen](https://libraries.io/npm/cordova-plugin-blurry-privacy-screen)

Comment: That plugin is iOS only.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it in this way:

```
constructor(public platform: Platform) {
    super(platform, {
        hideScreenOnBackground: true
    });
}
```